# What exactly is this process of adding hops called?

Tags: hops

Instead of using a hop bag last brew, I just added a couple of hop pellets straight to the wort. This gave an altogether different taste. I really enjoyed the taste of the hops. It just tasted like good health to me. It was earthy and wholesome and I loved it, I just would like to know what this process is called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked through my beer books and I couldn't find a single word that describes the addition of hops. Generally brewers describe the addition of hops based on their intended flavoring. Bittering additions or aroma additions. There are a variety of additions depending on timing. Here is a partial list:

First Wort Hopping - Added before the wort is boiled

Bittering - 90-45 minutes before end of wort boiling

Flavoring - 40-20 minutes before end of wort boiling

Finishing - 15-0 minutes before end of wort boiling

Flameout - after the finish of boil and before pitching yeast

Dry Hopping - during or after beer fermenting

[How Hops are used](http://howtobrew.com/book/section-1/hops/how-are-they-used)